Does "shift of terms" in a Faber–Schauder series expansion of f ∈ C[0,1] produce an element of C[0,1]?
Question
Let $\{e_n : n=0, 1, \dots \}$ be a Faber–Schauder basis of $C[0,1]$ (see: Example 4.1.11 in  [1]). Is the following function well-defined:
$$
\begin{align}
T \colon C[0,1] \times \mathbb{R} &\to C[0,1] \\
(f, \beta) = \left(\sum \alpha_n e_n, \beta\right) &\mapsto \beta e_0 + \sum \alpha_n e_{n+1} 
\end{align} 
$$
Note that the problem is in the shift in $\sum \alpha_n e_{n+1}$. I don't see how we can guarantee that $\sum \alpha_n e_{n+1}$ represents an element of $C[0,1]$.
Context and a bonus question
I was wondering about alternative ways to set up a linear homeomorphism between $C[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$ and $C[0,1]$. The mentioned map $T$ is a candidate.
Showing this isomorphism is a crucial step in proving that $C[0,1]$ is isomorphic to its square.
A classical way to construct such isomorphism is due to Banach (see: Section Products of Banach spaces in [2]).
We can ask a more general question: Fix a Banach space $E$ and a Schauder basis $\{e_n : n\in ℕ \}$ of our choosing (maybe with some property) let
$$
S:= \{ (\alpha_n) \in ℝ^ℕ : \sum \alpha_n e_n \in E\}.
$$
What can we say about the structure of $S$? How does it relate to the properties of selected Faber–Schauder basis?
In particular, is $S$ shift-invariant?
Let's end with a trivial observation:
Sometimes $S$ is shift invariant.
Indeed, let $c_0$ be a space real sequences that converge to zero with the supremum norm. Fix the Schauder basis  $\{ (0,\dots, 0,1 (n \text{-th place}),0, \dots) : n =1,2, \dots \}$. Then the corresponding space of sequences is shift invariant. That is
$$
\sum \alpha_n e_n \in c_0 \implies \sum \alpha_n e_{n+1} \in c_0.
$$
And othertimes Faber–Schauder basis is not shift invariant (see David Gao's comment).

I will be glad to hear your thoughts, comments, or literature. Thanks!
Bibliography

R. E. Megginson, An introduction to Banach space theory. in Graduate texts in mathematics, no. 183. New York: Springer, 1998.

S. Banach, Theory of linear operations. in North-Holland mathematical library, no. 38. Amsterdam New York Oxford: North-Holland, 1987.



For the bonus question, you definitely need more than just ${e_n}$ being a Schauder basis. For example, in $\ell^2$, if you let $e_n = (n!)f_n$ where ${f_n}$ is the standard orthonormal basis, then $(\frac{1}{(n+1)!})_n \in S$ but its rightward shift, $(\frac{1}{n!})_n \notin S$. (I doubt even a normalized Schauder basis works, but perhaps an unconditional normalized Schauder basis would be enough?)

@DavidGao thank you for your explicit and nice example :). I have added a reference to your comment. I suspect that being shift invariant is rather an anomaly. I edited my post and hope the bonus question is more clear now.
